# linux x86_64 vm gcc error in architecture of executable output, exec file format error

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86-64, file-format

I'm using GNU/Linux 64 bit Oracle VM to compile a simple c program main.c:
`int main(){ return 0; }`
**gcc command is:** gcc -c main.c -o output
When running: ./output, it **results in error**  :
"Cannot execute binary file: Exec format error"

**[Why the gcc compilation results an executable that doesn't correspond to the architecture of the machine(SYSV and not GNU/Linux)?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1erVx.png)** 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-c` flag tells `gcc` to generate an *object file*. Object files are not executable, instead they are input to the linker which is used to create the executable file.

Either drop the `-c` flag:

```
gcc main.c -o output
```

Or build the object file and then link it:

```
gcc -c main.c
gcc main.o -o output
```

For more information about the command-line arguments for GCC, please [read the documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/) for your version of GCC.

Comment: please help in my hashing question Sir
only you can help me @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: @david12345 Without the full requirements and specification of your assignment, no one can help you more. And the only way to help you with the requirements and specification, is basically to do your assignment instead if you, which no one really want to do or have time with.